Probability distribution of a random variable defined in terms of other random variables
An unbiased cubical dice has number 1 on 1 face, number 2 on 2 faces and number 3 on 3 faces. The dice is rolled twice and the sum of the 2 rolls is denoted by the random variable X.
Obviously, I can manually calculate the probabilities $ P(X=x) $, but I was thinking of solving this in terms of another random variable.
Let Y be the random variable denoting the outcome of 1 roll of the dice.
$$ P(Y=y) = \frac{y}{6}, 1 \leq y\leq 3 $$
Additionally,
$$ Y_1 + Y_2 = X $$ where $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent observations of $Y$
However, I'm struggling to find the probability distribution of X using these relationships.
I'm aware that when it comes to continuous random variables where $ G(Y) = X $, knowing $P(X\leq x)$ and using $P(G^{-1}(X) \leq y) $ to solve for $ P(Y \leq y)$ and thus $P(Y=y)$ by differentiation.
I'm wondering if there is a similar, more general method to find probability distribution functions for

Random variables in terms of independent observations of other random variables
Discrete random variables


Since you want to find the distribution of sum of two independent variates, you have to work with $G$ which is a function of two variables. So one possible way is to do it by $\sum_{k}P(Y_{1}+Y_{2}\leq x , Y_{2}=k)$. Otherwise, you find the joint pmf of $Y_{1}$ and $Y_{2}$ by multiplying . And then you compute the joint pmf/pdf of $U,V$ where $U=Y_{1}+Y_{2}$ and $V=Y_{2}$ by applying change of variables. Then you integrate over $V$ to find the pmf/pdf of $U$. So, I am talking about using $G(Y_{1},Y_{2})=Y_{1}+Y_{2}$ as a function of two variables.

Wikipédia's article on the convolution of probability distributions may help.

Thank you @Mr.GandalfSauron, I'll look into these techniques!

Thank you @nejimban too!
